# iOS Swift performSegueWithIdentifier for sending data

Tags: ios, swift

I want to send data to my adapter view where it should put correct data to it.I send the data over the  "exerciseName" variable.In the print its correct but when it reaches the destination the second view it becomes nil.Please help

```
var workoutInfoData : WorkoutInfo!
var RoundLabels = ["Round 1","Round 2","Round 3","Round 4","Round 5","Round 6","Round 7","Round 8","Round 9","Round 10","Round 11","Round 12"]
var exerciseName:String = ""

var roundPosition = [Int]()
let numberOfExercises = 1
var scrollerSize = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //self.workoutTitle.title! = workoutInfoData.workout_name

    navigationItem.title = workoutInfoData.workout_name

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func workoutBack(sender: AnyObject) {
 self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return RoundLabels.count

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell : RoundWorkoutCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! RoundWorkoutCell
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! RoundWorkoutCell;
    }
    let exerviseName = RoundLabels[indexPath.row]

    if(indexPath.row == 1){
    }


    for countMe in 0..<self.numberOfExercises {
        if(countMe<1){
            roundPosition.append(5)
        }else{
            roundPosition.append(115+roundPosition[countMe-1])
        }
        scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition[countMe]
    }

    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(scrollerSize),115)
    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default


    for index in 0..<self.numberOfExercises {
        var imageView : UIImageView
        imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:roundPosition[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 110 ))
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        let label1: UILabel = UILabel()
        label1.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 20 )
        label1.textColor = UIColor(red:17/255.0, green: 22/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha:1.0)
        label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label1.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-CondensedLight", size: 14)
        label1.text = "Pushups"
        cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label1)

        let frame1 = CGRect(x:roundPosition[index]+10,y:25, width:90, height: 90 )
        let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "sit_thrust") as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitle("air_sit_front_raise", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0/255,green:0/255,blue:0/255,alpha:0.0), forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(button)

        let label: UILabel = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition[index],y: 115, width:110, height: 20 )
        label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "30sec"
        cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label)

    }



    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_Label.text = exerviseName

    return cell as RoundWorkoutCell
}

func buttonClick(sender:AnyObject){
    exerciseName = String(sender.currentTitle)
    //print(sender.currentTitle)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showExercise", sender:exerciseName)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showExercise" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewExerciseFromMenu
        //vc.exerciseGet = UIImage(named: "sit_thrust")!
        //vc.title = "SIT THRUSTS"
        print(exerciseName)
        vc.exerciseGet = exerciseName

        navigationItem.title = "easy"
    }
}
```

The adapter view

```
 @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var musInvImageHolder: UIImageView!

var exerciseGet: String = ""

var image = UIImage()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //var exerciseCurrent: String
    print(exerciseGet)
    switch(String(exerciseGet)){
    case "air_sit_front_raise":
        self.title = "AIR SIT FRONT RAISE"
        musInvImageHolder.image = UIImage(named: "mus_inv_20")
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("air_sit_front_raise", withExtension: "gif")!
        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        imageView.image =  UIImage.animatedImageWithData(imageData!)
        break;
```

Comment: Can you please show your `ViewExerciseFromMenu ` code and place where you are trying to access `exerciseGet`.

Comment: Yes sure there it is

Comment: I'll add a code snippet as an example.

Comment: Sorry the output at the adapter view is not nil its good but the problem is that the String? and String are not comapred

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing - not clear from your last comment. Why are you doing `String(exerciseGet)`? - `exerciseGet` should be a string already.

Comment: I noticed that I'm sending the currentTitle from the sender "sender.currentTitle" and when i put that into a switch it asks for case .Some("").... I'm not sure if that is a problem because when i give it a string "some exercise" it works.

Comment: The key topic to understand is [optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)- the 'Some' you see in Xcode is to do with the implementation of optionals. You need to make sure that the value you are dealing with is a string, and not an optional containing a string. `sender.currentTitle` probably returns an optional containing a string. You will need to check whether it is `nil`, and if not, dereference the optional to get the string inside

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix for it

```
@IBOutlet var roundExercisesTable: UITableView!
var workoutInfoData : WorkoutInfo!
var RoundLabels = ["Round 1","Round 2","Round 3","Round 4","Round 5","Round 6","Round 7","Round 8","Round 9","Round 10","Round 11","Round 12"]
var exerciseName:String? = ""
var myButtons: [Int : UIButton] = [:]
var roundPosition = [Int]()
let numberOfExercises = 1
var scrollerSize = 0


let exerciseInfo=ExercisesInfo()
    override func viewDidLoad()



{
        super.viewDidLoad()

    //self.workoutTitle.title! = workoutInfoData.workout_name

    navigationItem.title = workoutInfoData.workout_name

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func workoutBack(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return RoundLabels.count

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell : RoundWorkoutCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! RoundWorkoutCell
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! RoundWorkoutCell;
    }
    let exerviseName = RoundLabels[indexPath.row]

    if(indexPath.row == 1){
    }


    for countMe in 0..<self.numberOfExercises {
        if(countMe<1){
            roundPosition.append(5)
        }else{
            roundPosition.append(115+roundPosition[countMe-1])
        }
        scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition[countMe]
    }

    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(scrollerSize),115)
    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default


    for index in 0..<self.numberOfExercises {
        var imageView : UIImageView
        imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:roundPosition[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 110 ))
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        let label1: UILabel = UILabel()
        label1.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 20 )
        label1.textColor = UIColor(red:17/255.0, green: 22/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha:1.0)
        label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label1.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-CondensedLight", size: 14)
        label1.text = "Pushups"
        cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label1)

        let frame1 = CGRect(x:roundPosition[index]+10,y:25, width:90, height: 90 )
        let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "sit_thrust") as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitle("air_sit_front_raise", forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0/255,green:0/255,blue:0/255,alpha:0.0), forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(button)

        let label: UILabel = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition[index],y: 115, width:110, height: 20 )
        label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "30sec"
        cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label)

    }



    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_Label.text = exerviseName

    return cell as RoundWorkoutCell
}

func buttonClick(sender:AnyObject){
    exerciseName = sender.currentTitle
    //print(sender.currentTitle)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showExercise", sender:exerciseName)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showExercise" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewExerciseFromMenu
        //vc.exerciseGet = UIImage(named: "sit_thrust")!
        //vc.title = "SIT THRUSTS"
        print(exerciseName)
        vc.exerciseGet = exerciseName!
        navigationItem.title = exerciseInfo.hradnesExerciseDeterminer(exerciseName!)
    }
}
```